# Can an abelian surface be bielliptic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

Is an abelian surface containing an elliptic curve a bielliptic surface?

Suppose I have an abelian surface $A$ over the complex numbers that contains an elliptic curve $E$. Then
$A \to A/E$ is an elliptic fibration. The abelian surface $A$ will also contain a complementary elliptic curve $F$. Then $A \to A/F$ should also define an elliptic fibration.

Does this make A bielliptic? And does this always hold so long as it contains one elliptic curve?

Comment: What is the definition of bielliptic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperelliptic_surface the Albanese morphism of a bielliptic surface has 1-dimensional fibers, while the Albanese morphism of an abelian surface is the identity. So, no, an abelian surface is never bielliptic.

Comment: Thank you very much!